# TeamCity tfs pull on agent

Tags: teamcity

I have a teamcity server running on a my mac with an agent on my tfs/vs2010 build machine. I keep getting errors every time i start the build that say "Team Foundation Server VCS Support runs only under Windows".  My first reaction is that the webserver is trying to pull the code (the mac and not the windows build machine).  I changed the VCS checkout mode to "Automatically on Agent", but I am still getting that error. Is there anything I need to change so that all the pulling is done on the agent and not the webserver?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also tried making it not shared among all projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly TeamCity server has to be installed on Windows to communicate with TFS.
Even with agent-side checkout, the server does communicate to VCS directly - to monitor changes, show source diffs, etc.
And in case of TFS, we need to use TFS client (Team Explorer) that's not available for Mac OS.

Comment: Can you not configure Team City to use Team Explorer Everywhere? TEE support mac just fine...

Answer (score 0):

From now it's possible to try out EAP version of the cross-platform TFS plugin for TeamCity. As result you will able to install TeamCity server and agents at the Linux, Mac OS or Windows platforms and checkout TFS repositories.

You can read more details about how to get it in the announcement:
http://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2015/12/teamcity-cross-platform-tfs-support/